# Show I let RenderFlex overflowed unhandled?

Tags: layout, widget, flutter

In Flutter Widget, sometimes layout overflow cause exception in debug mode and show like  with number pixel overflow. In release mode, it looks fine.

Should I leave such layout overflow?

Answer (score 3):

No.

These  are there for a reason. Flutter is not like HTML, you should *never* have overflow. If you have some, it's a bug and needs to be fixed.
Same goes for failing asserts. They'll work in release mode, but that's still a bug.

If you want to have an overflow, consider using [`OverflowBox`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/OverflowBox-class.html) instead